# Log Stacktrace to FirebaseDatabase in UncaughtExceptionHandler, problem calling default uncaughtException method

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm currently stuck with UncaughtExceptionHandler and Firebase Database in my Android Kotlin App.

My plan:
In the case of an uncaught exception, log the stack trace to Google Firebase.

I already have an BaseCompatActivity with an UncaughtExceptionHandler. All activities inherit from this class.

The only and the interesting part from BaseCompatActivity follows:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val currentUncaughtExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler({ thread, exception ->
        val exStackTraceString = StringWriter()
        exception.printStackTrace(PrintWriter(exStackTraceString))
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/exception-log").push().setValue(exStackTraceString.toString()).addOnCompleteListener {
            currentUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, exception)
        }
    })
}
```

Everything is working except the the default method call for currentUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, exception) because this line is never called. It seems that the complete listener never gets called. This leads to an non-closed, unusable App after the exception occured :-(
The logging into the Firebase Database is working. The only broken thing is the listener callback method.

I don't want to use System.exit() because this breaks the Exception Chain.

Can you help me?

Comment: Usually people use tools like Crashlytics to automatically capture and log the uncaught exceptions.  Logging to a database seems like a lot of unnecessary work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`:

"Set the default handler invoked when a thread abruptly terminates due to an uncaught exception"

Your call to your Firebase Database uses an asynchronous callback. Without more information, it's hard to be sure, but considering your UI is getting stuck, something off of your Main thread is getting killed. You're able to make the call, but the result doesn't have a thread to return to because the thread has been terminated.

If you're using Firebase, I'd suggest looking at Crashlytics, they have a method for handling this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I followed https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android and it works fine. Thanks as well to Doug Stevenson because of his really true comment.